# How to get current month in string and year in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I want to show date in string format as current month name(String) and year(e.g -> SEPTEMBER, 2019). How to write query for this in PostgreSQL?

I tried this query:

```
select 
     date(date_trunc('month', current_date));
```

but it gives me only current months starting date.

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=postgresql+date+formatting&t=vivaldi&ia=web

Answer (score 3):

Try `to_char()` and add the year [formatter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE) to the string like this:

```
SELECT to_char(current_date, 'MONTH YYYY')
```

This will return:

```
SEPTEMBER 2019
```

Here's a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/36995)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to format the output of a DATE value, use [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE)

```
select to_char(current_date, 'Month, yyyy');
```

Comment: @Nitishawasthi  that example is in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

we can do it like this also in Postgresql -

***SELECT TO_CHAR(NOW() :: DATE, 'Month , yyyy');***

output - September, 2019